# Recursive CTE-Find all Employees Below Manager

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, recursive-cte

I created a sample fiddle for this [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/43265/1)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
    [userId] [int] ,
    [userName] [varchar](50) ,
    [managerId] [int] ,
   )

INSERT INTO dbo.Users
    ([userId], [userName], [managerId])
VALUES
(1,'Darry',NULL),
(2,'Cono',1),
(3,'Abros',2),
(4,'Natesh',1),
(5,'Ani',3),
(6,'Raju',5),
(7,'Pinky',5),
(8,'Miya',4)
```

My requirement is like displaying all employees hierarchy below that particular manager

Here is what i tried

```
WITH UserCTE AS (
  SELECT userId, userName, managerId, 0 AS EmpLevel
  FROM Users where managerId IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT usr.userId, usr.userName, usr.managerId, mgr.[EmpLevel]+1
  FROM Users AS usr
    INNER JOIN UserCTE AS mgr
      ON usr.managerId = mgr.userId where usr.managerId IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT * 
  FROM UserCTE AS u where u.ManagerId=3
  ORDER BY EmpLevel;
```

**Output :**

```
userName
--------
    Ani
```

The output that i am expecting is, if i give a ManagerId 3,then following employees should be shown

```
1.Abros
2.Ani
3.Raju
4.Pinky
```

Can anyone help on this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this. Filter has to be applied in the `Anchor query` of CTE

```
WITH UserCTE
     AS (SELECT userId,
                userName,
                managerId,
                0 AS EmpLevel
         FROM   [Users]
         WHERE  managerId = 3
         UNION ALL
         SELECT usr.userId,
                usr.userName,
                usr.managerId,
                mgr.[EmpLevel] + 1
         FROM   [Users] AS usr
                INNER JOIN UserCTE AS mgr
                        ON usr.managerId = mgr.userId
         WHERE  usr.managerId IS NOT NULL)
SELECT *
FROM   UserCTE AS u
ORDER  BY EmpLevel;
```

### [FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/43265/6)

Comment: is it possible to modify it like if a particular employee is not a manager,then return same employee itself.eg: if i pass manager id 8,then it should return details of user "Miya" itself

Comment: @vmb - that you should ask it as an another question or update your question with this request.

Comment: @vmb You got the answer only because of the last line `SELECT userId, userName, managerId, 0 AS EmpLevel from Users where userId=8` CTE is not used in that query

Comment: i will mark it as answer after few more rounds of testing

Comment: @vmb - Take your time :)