# Find all people who work under a certain manager (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, recursion, common-table-expression

I'm currently working on trying to find a list of every employee who works under a given manager. Right now, I have the following solution, which uses a recursive CTE: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oTTpJ9tTudkFrqy1WJghZj/0

The problem with this solution is that it only works with MySQL 8.0+, and I'm not sure how many of the other SQL distros support CTE. Is there a SQL-agnostic solution to this problem that will work with older versions of MySQL? I tried to solve this using loops where I had a function with a while loop that selected employee ids where manager id in (list of employee ids from previous iteration) and concatenated the result set, but you can't actually use GROUP_CONCAT in a where in clause as far as I can tell.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: "SQL-agnostic"?  Recursive CTEs are part of the SQL standard.  Take it up with vendors if they don't (yet) support them.  Many, if not most, databases do.

Comment: Here it is : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27631884/recursive-cte-find-all-employees-below-manager

Comment: Hi @MatiasBarrios, this is for sqlserver what you have sent ? OP needs it for MySQL. Also, he has the solution with cte ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff This is the impression I got, was just looking for something that will work on older MySQL versions (which do not support CTEs).

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be solved using traditional way of SQL

```
SELECT 
e.employee_id AS EmployeeId,
CONCAT(e.first_name, ' ', e.last_name) AS EmployeeName,
CONCAT(m.first_name, ' ', m.last_name) AS ManagerName
FROM Employees e
INNER JOIN Employees m ON e.manager_id = m.employee_id
ORDER BY m.employee_id, e.employee_id
```

Hope this will reduce much complexity

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately this solution does not allow you to specify a given manager to find the subordinates for. It just lists out the entire table and manager for each person. If you wanted to specify a manager, it would only go 1 level deep because it isn't recursive.